# The average density inside the particle horizon (observable universe) $ρ(t)$?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, density

Does anyone know the average density of our universe and the particle horizon function as a function of time?

The average density inside the particle horizon(observable universe) : $ρ(t) $?

Radius function of the observable universe : $R(t)$?

I would appreciate it if you could let me know of any material with data or graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your concept of "average density" is the amount of mass of matter per unit of volume: e.g., kilograms per cubic meter. I suggest you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe, or other online references. Wikipedia says the density is M(t_0) = 9.9 x 10^-27 kg/m^3, which is about six protons per cubic meter. This is the **current** value of density. The density varies with time as follows: M(t) = M(t_0)/a(t)^3, where **a** is the scale factor. Solving the Friedmann equation for a(t) is quite complicated. One can calculate an approximate solution for most of the time history assuming that (1) the curvature of the universe is flat, and (2) that mass density is large compared with the radiation density. See http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/denpar.html. The current ratio of mass to radiation density is approximately 3277. Thus when a = 1/3277, the two densities will be equal. See [https://lweb.cfa.harvard.edu/~hrs/ay45/2001/CMBPhysRep2000.pdf](https://lweb.cfa.harvard.edu/%7Ehrs/ay45/2001/CMBPhysRep2000.pdf). This occurred approximately 100,000 years after the big bang.  (I am not presently able to calculate the function of the observable universe radius as a function of time.)